# UpdatePanel: Move from url query params to async content

Tags: asp.net, performance, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, postback

A rough layout of my ASP.NET site is as follows

[image: Site layout]

The main navigation currently relies on url query parameters (i.e `<a href="/?category=InStock">`) to determine what charting control is dynamically loaded.

I would like to improve on this design by adding an `UpdatePanel` to this design and having the panels update the chart / graph when a new category is selected. Since the anchor tags trigger a Page.Redirect when clicked I'm wondering if this can still be done with update panels or if I will have to modify my navigation `<a href>` tags to be `Button` controls?

The main reason we decided to go with `<a href>` tags was for the ability to bookmark a site and save the state of the page so the user return to that  specific chart when needed.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is change your `<a href>` tags to button or linkbutton controls, ditch your current querystring driven logic, and just change the graph based on which button was clicked instead.

You could then add your update panel(s), enable browser history management in your ScriptManager and create history points when each button is clicked.

See this msdn article for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488548.aspx

What this does is inject the current page information in the browser's history and encodes the state that you specify in the querystring automatically.

This means the user can bookmark the current state of the page and everything is still AJAX'd.

Another good article covering the ASP.NET AJAX History feature:
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020103240/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/100808-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've implemented the LinkButton approach suggested. However the logic to build out my controls listed above (`UserContentHeader`, `Widgets`, `LinkButtons`,`ChartGraph` )occurs in the `Page_Init` event handler. Therefore by the time my `OnClick` event fires for the LinkButton the event has already fired.

Comment: The `OnClick` event is what contains the key information that determines what new controls to load based on the category of information to show.